# Extending Intent class in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to extend the "android.content.Intent" class by adding a private attribute of a custom class. My goal is to send complex objects from the main Activity to a background Service. 
The extension itself is not a problem, the class gets compiled without any errors and the project runs. The only problem is that the BroadcastReceiver does not receive the modified Intent and the "onReceive" method gets never called. 
It there any way to pass complex objects with the help of Intents?

Thanks in advance, 
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your objects need to implement the [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface. Then you can pass them in your intents using [Intent#putExtra(String, Parcelable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%29) and retrieve them using (MyObject) [Intent#getParcelableExtra(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableExtra%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Aye, or just try sending the required data using the simple types in the intent's extra, I think implementing parcelable is an overkill in most cases.